# ViewModel Can't Seem to Observe MutableLiveData

Tags: android, repository, observable, viewmodel

I have a repository that sets data like so:

```
private MutableLiveData<JSONObject> myVocab = new MutableLiveData<>();

public Repo(Context context) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        service.execute(() -> {
            myVocab = jsonReader.readJSONFromAssets(context, "myVocab.json")
        });
        service.shutdown();
}

public MutableLiveData<JSONObject> getVocab() { return myVocab; }
```

It correctly reads in json and saves it to myVoc, I've already checked.

I also have a ViewModel that listens to the vocab object and then does stuff with it:

```
private MediatorLiveData<JSONObject> vocab = new MediatorLiveData<>();

/* CONSTRUCTOR */
public WordsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    wordsRepository = Repo.getInstance(application);

    vocab.addSource(_wordsRepository.getVocab(),
            jsonObject -> vocab.setValue(jsonObject));

    doStuffWithVocab();
}
```

However, the observer never gets called (I've put logs in there to check). I've run into this issue with several apps now and can't seem to ever resolve it except through hacks.

Why doesn't my observer work? (It works in MainActivity, just not the ViewModel).

Comment: "the observer never gets called" -- you don't seem to have an observer. You connect the `getVocab()` `LiveData` to the `MediatorLiveData`, but that's not an observer. Where is the observer?

Comment: Please note that the Live Data will not emit any value to any Lifecycle Owner which is not in active state. I think should check the state of your activity/fragment at the time you update your live data's value